# Gradle sync BUILD SUCCESSFUL but Make project failed

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

When i do a Gradle sync it says build successful but when i try to Make project it fails giving the following error:

```
Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle/1.4.21/kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle-1.4.21.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

My Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
//        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.21"

        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
plugins {
//    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version '1.4.21'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven" }
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

        }
        maven {
            url "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
            credentials {
                username 'braintree_team_sdk'
                password 'AKCp8jQcoDy2hxSWhDAUQKXLDPDx6NYRkqrgFLRc3qDrayg6rrCbJpsKKyMwaykVL8FWusJpp'
            }
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/oss-releases-local'

        }
        jcenter()
        google()

        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
```

I am not an android dev I know very little about android dev so please explain in a little more detail for me :)  i know something about bintray not being available anymore but not sure how to edit the gradle to remove this

Comment: A year later... and I have the same exact issue. Have you been able to solve the mystery? Why would `Sync` end with BUILD SUCCESSFUL but `Make Project` FAIL?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are:

1. asking for the wrong library module (check your module build.gradle)
2. You don't specify the right repository in your top level build.gradle
3. You are off line.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but all of those check out and i am not offline.

Comment: is there any more info i can give that could help you help me?