# Sync ends with BUILD SUCCESSFUL but Make Project FAILS

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

All SO post on this subject (except for [an unanswered one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70393865/2597758)) describe the exact opposite situation: Build successful but Sync fails.

My situation is that I installed Android Studio for the first time (2021.3.1.17) and successfully imported an old (but working) Eclipse/ADT project of mine: Sync completes successfully, albeit with several warnings:

```
> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

It also warns about the Java version:

```
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
 Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\jre
 You can try some of the following options:
  - changing the IDE settings.
  - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
  - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
Gradle settings
```

But when I try to `Build` > `Make Project`, it surprisingly ends with an **ERROR**:

```
Build file 'C:\Users\WebViewer\StudioProjects\MyApp\billing\build.gradle' line: 1

A problem occurred evaluating project ':billing'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
      Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\jre
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I understand the warnings (definitely good ones, prompting to update to current versions, and I eliminated the Java version one via `File` > `Settings` > `Build Tools` > `Gradle`) but... if **Sync** ends successfully, why would **Make Project** fail completely?

As a newcomer to Android Studio (IntelliJ + [Gradle](https://tomgregory.com/gradle-tutorial-for-complete-beginners/)), I am confused by this discrepancy. Could someone please shed light on the **essential difference** between `Sync`, `Make Project` and `Rebuild Project`?